# Advice on Configuring .HTaccess file to Redirect HTTP Subdomain to HTTPS Equivalent

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https, subdomain

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this question, but I've scoured through through available threads and its either not there or I'm too ignorant to recognize it starting in my face. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545097/redirect-subdomain-request-to-subdirectory-https-using-htaccess) seems to be the answer, but I just can't configure correctly.

**Question**: How do I set up .htaccess so that all subdomains are forwarded to their https equivalents, while also allowing the main domain itself get ported to its https equivalent? In other words:

> 1. hxxp://subdomain1.domain.com --> hxxps://subdomain1.domain.com
> 2. hxxp://subdomain2.domain.com --> hxxps://subdomain2.domain.com
>
> ...and so on, but also...
>
> 3. hxxp://domain.com --> hxxps://domain.com

**Current Configuration**:
My .htaccess is set up to provide an unconditional forward as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

To achieve what I want, I would think that there must be some way to define a wildcard and pass the result of that wildcard as the subdomain - whether, subdomain1, subdomain2 or a value of nothing - to the actual redirect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should allow you to capture the subdomain as well as the request.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This rule however, will not work for requests that do not contain a subdirectory, so you actually need two rules.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. THANK YOU! It works perfectly. Out of curiosity, why is this so complex? In other words, why is the variable being defined as the potential subdomain --> (.*)?

Comment: Basically, you need to capture the subdomain in parenthesis in the conditional so that in the RewriteRule you can be sure you are redirecting the user to the proper subdomain. Normally, you don't have to worry about this because most of the time when you do a rewrite you are doing it internally. Since you are changing protocols though, and can't simply make a local redirect, you need this extra step.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto your subdomain folder
2. Create .htaccess file in this folder
3. and paste this code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```