# htaccess with wildcard SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, wildcard

We have a Wildcard SSL Certificate that is supposed to work on any subdomain of a given domain.

So in this server we have this file structure:

**/home/DOMAIN/public_html/subdomainx

/home/DOMAIN/public_html/subdomainy**

etc...

Now, the Certificate is installed, but when you visit any subdomain over https (example: **hxxps://subdomainx.domain.com** ) it points to

**/home/DOMAIN/public_html/index.php**

We need that when you visit a subdomain via https
**hxxps://subdomainx.domain.com**

That it points to the the same directory that it's http equivalent:
**/home/DOMAIN/public_html/subdomainx**

Our provider tells us that this is not possible, that the current behaviour is correct, and that we should do some htaccess to achieve this.

I've tried a few things, incluiding this solution, that seems to be what I need: [Advice on Configuring .HTaccess file to Redirect HTTP Subdomain to HTTPS Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365612/advice-on-configuring-htaccess-file-to-redirect-http-subdomain-to-https-equival)

But can't get it to work.

Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: mod_rewrite can likely do this. This does belong on serverfault though as it's not a programming question.

Comment: All right, thanks. I'll check over there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the **[R]** flag in your rewrite rule, or the hostname in the target. You want to rewrite the URI so that a "subdomainx" is prepended to it. Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On

# We don't want the main domain or www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).*)\.domain.com$ [NC]

# Make sure that if we rewrite, the destination actually exists (to prevent loops and properly return 404's)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} -d

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Note that the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_URI}` checks *have to be made* so that proper 404's get returned without information disclosure. This makes it so when you request for http://test.domain.com/badfile.html, the 404 message says "/badfile.html" is not found, instead of "/test/badfile.html" is not found.